# jQuery dynamic table formatting differently with different positions on leading <tr> tags

Tags: jquery, html

I've got a simple table that's dynamically printed on the page after a button click (reads a JS array).

```
<input type="submit" id = "marimc2013" class="campbutton" value="Click">
<div id="searcharea"></div>

function getArray(video) { 
 if (searchQuery === video[4]) {
   if (video[6] === 1)     
     $('#searcharea').append('<tr><td><h4>Masterclass ' + video[5] + '</h4></td></tr><tr><td>' + video[0] + '</td><td><h3>Composer: ' + video[1] + '\n</h3><h3>Player: ' + video[2] + '\n</h3><h3>Piece: ' + video[3] + '\n</h3><input type = "button" value = "  Play  " class = "play"/></td>');  

   else              
     $('#searcharea').append('<td>' + video[0] + '</td><td><h3>Composer: ' + video[1] + '\n</h3><h3>Player: ' + video[2] + '\n</h3><h3>Piece: ' + video[3] + '\n</h3><input type = "button" value = "  Play  " class = "play"/></td>');   

 } 

  else 
    noResultCount++;                    

} // End getArray()

 $('.campbutton').on('click', function () {
    $('#searcharea').html('<table>'); // First print table tag only
    searchQuery = $(this).attr('id');
  for (i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {   
      getArray(videos[i]);           
  }
 });
```

This will print the table in a surprising manner [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/shindig/8q9nx2xg/). Notice that the first td prints (Mastserclass I), but it prints the second video on a new row. I don't see anything in my code that would print the next video on a new row. Is there a new tr entering in somewhere?

Now, if I make a very subtle change and put the tr tag here along with the table tag:

```
$('#searcharea').html('<table><tr>'); // Now, <tr> placed along with <table>
```

and then remove it from the function on the first append:

```
 $('#searcharea').append('<td><h4>Masterclass ' + video[5]... // No leading tr
```

Here, the first td (Masterclass I) isn't printed [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/shindig/wzxd4p45/2/) but both videos are on the same row.

I'm trying to get both the "Masterclass I" to print at the top and have the elements on the same row (as they should be). My biggest question is why it should make any difference whether the tr tag is appended onto the table when the table is created, or if it's included in the html method before the table is created? I don't get it.

Huge thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Don't try to build HTML in pieces like this. Adding only an opening tag like `<table>`, without the matching `</table>`, is going to go badly and will result in unpredictable results. Build all of your HTML, then add it at once, or at least build it one complete element at a time.

Comment: Building tables like this is new for me. Thanks for your explanation. Now I get it. Looks like others perhaps didn't like the way I asked the question. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you append the table and then you apen the rows **IN** the table, same thing inside the function, you append the row and then the cells **IN** the rows:

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/8q9nx2xg/8/

```
var videos = [ 
    ['Some Text', 'Beethoven', 'Jill', 'Beethoven Op.101', 'marimc2013', 'I', 1], 
    ['Some Text', 'Beethoven', 'Jack', 'Beethoven Tempest', 'marimc2013', 'I', 'e']
];

var noResultCount = 0;
var searchQuery = "";

function getArray(video) { 
 if (searchQuery === video[4]) {
   if (video[6] === 1) {   
     $('#searcharea table').append('<tr></tr>');
     $('#searcharea table tr').append('<td><h4>Masterclass ' + video[5] + '</h4></td></tr><tr><td>' + video[0] + '</td><td><h3>Composer: ' + video[1] + '\n</h3><h3>Player: ' + video[2] + '\n</h3><h3>Piece: ' + video[3] + '\n</h3><input type = "button" value = "  Play  " class = "play"/></td>');
    }
   else {           
     $('#searcharea table').append('<tr></tr>');
     $('#searcharea table tr').append('<td>' + video[0] + '</td><td><h3>Composer: ' + video[1] + '\n</h3><h3>Player: ' + video[2] + '\n</h3><h3>Piece: ' + video[3] + '\n</h3><input type = "button" value = "  Play  " class = "play"/></td>');   
    }
 } 
else {noResultCount++; }                  

} // End of getArray()


 $('.campbutton').on('click', function () {
    $('#searcharea').append('<table></table>');
    searchQuery = $(this).attr('id');
    for (i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {   
      getArray(videos[i]);           
    }
 });
```

**As the result of that code, you have this:**

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Some Text</td>
            <td>
                <h3>Composer: Beethoven</h3>
                <h3>Player: Jill</h3>
                <h3>Piece: Beethoven Op.101</h3>
                <input type="button" value="  Play  " class="play">
            </td>
            <td>Some Text</td>
            <td>
                <h3>Composer: Beethoven</h3>
                <h3>Player: Jack</h3>
                <h3>Piece: Beethoven Tempest</h3>
                <input type="button" value="  Play  " class="play">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Some Text</td>
            <td>
                <h3>Composer: Beethoven</h3>
                <h3>Player: Jack</h3>
                <h3>Piece: Beethoven Tempest</h3>
                <input type="button" value="  Play  " class="play">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Ah, I see. I didn't understand how to use append tables correctly with jQuery. Thank you!

Comment: I noticed that the "Masterclass I" isn't printing. It needs to be on its own row (at the top). Been trying but no luck.

Comment: It had a `tr` inside. Once removed, Masterclass is there: http://jsfiddle.net/8q9nx2xg/30/ ... Follow the same principle so you can build any design you want: append the table, append the row, and even more if you want: append the cell, append the cell content, etc. I didn't take it too far because it was just to show you the way. You'll do it great.